# What's this new "get updates" box and why doesn't it have any functions?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I've seen this across nine different Stacks I follow, so I presume it's everywhere.

The last few days, I've been getting a little box in most (all?) questions with a bell icon inside and "get updates on questions and answers" -- but there's no active text in the box, the bell isn't active, and the only function that appears to be available is to close the box with the X in the upper right.

Is this a preview of an upcoming feature, a bug, or a bugged/failing feature that's supposed to be live?  I've looked in other parts of the UI and don't see anything that lets me specifically follow a given question or answer.  What's up with the bell box?

Comment: You might look at meta stack exchange and check there for an answer as they get more traffic than we do and someone with more knowledge on this feature might be able to help you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought I'd try one of the low-traffice Stacks first, because the main meta isn't always very friendly and might have enough traffic for my question to scroll off the first page without being read...

Comment: @JoeW So, apparently there's a new UI tag below each question, everywhere: "follow" in between "share edit close delete flag" somewhere.  Subtle enough to miss.

Comment: The "Get updates on questions and answers" box has an arrow pointing to the follow button.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe it's just my autism.  Change the interface and put a box with an arrow on it and I still miss the change...

Comment: To be fair, the contrast on the arrow is pretty bad.

Answer (score 4):

It's to draw attention to the new ['Follow Questions and Answers' feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232):

> You can follow any question or answer (that you did not author) by clicking on the [follow] button that is shown in the menu immediately below the post (alongside the [share] button):
>
> [image: Get updates on questions and answers]
>
> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices. You will not receive notifications for any action that you performed. As was mentioned in the earlier post, we are not making changes at this point to the notifications received by a post owner, or due to @mentions.